# Python - Use pkexec only one time in subprocess.run one time for multiple commands

Tags: python, linux, privileges, polkit

I need to use two commands requiring privileges and for this reason I'm using pkexec. My piece of code is:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.__binary = "/usr/bin/docker"
    self.docker_start = subprocess.run(["pkexec", "systemctl", "start", "docker"], capture_output=True)
    self.pulled_containers = subprocess.run(["pkexec", self.__binary, "ps", "-a", "--format", "'{{.Image}}'"], capture_output=True)
```

I would like to avoid that the request of password is prompting two times, and I would like to have only one time for both of the commands. Usually I can use `pkexec bash -c "command1; command2"` and I tried to use:

```
self.pulled_containers = subprocess.run(["pkexec", "bash", "-c", "\"systemctl start docker; docker ps -a --format '{{.Image}}'\""], capture_output=True)
```

but it seems to not work. Is there a good way to run two commands by subprocess by using pkexec (and the password prompt) only one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put double quotes (") for `-c` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

python << EOF
import subprocess
print(subprocess.run(["pkexec", "bash", "-c", "date; sleep 1; date"], capture_output=True).stdout.decode())
EOF
```